# removing the root element in xml in java

Tags: java

removing the root element in xml in java

Comment: It doesn't help that you've given a load of code which looks like it should be in a method, but not told us anything about where it is, or called it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: actually i want to remove <type id='01' details='looks'> </type> and want to take the values only <collection name='book'>        
<p num='id1' varie='var1'/>     
<p num='id2' Varie='var2'/>
</collection>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to replace the root element with its single child, right? So you want:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\ADMIN\Pictures\sample.xml");
doc.Root.ReplaceWith(doc.Root.Elements().Single());
```

That's all you should need to do. Then `doc`'s root element will be `<collection>`. I've just tried this, and it was fine.

If you really *have* to load the document as an `XElement` (why?) you could always just use:

```
rootElement = rootElement.Elements().Single();
```

You don't need to "remove" the root element - just navigate to it.

Comment: i am using xelement instead of xdocument so i dont find replacewith function for that

Comment: @newbie1: Well given that you're loading a document, I suggest you *use* `XDocument`. If not, you could always just say `rootElement = rootElement.Elements().Single()`.

Comment: oops i think i need to create a new question. Thought of updating the old post in different forum. but it dint work. sorry about that.

Comment: @newbie1: If it's a different problem, you should definitely ask a new question.